# Using ASP.Net Identity with model classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm new to ASP.Net Identity, and I'm looking for a good tutorial for using Identity in conjunction with other classes in my model.

As an example I have a basic Ratings class that looks like this (from a project *not* using Identity)

```
public class Rating
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

    }
```

And a User Class that looks a bit like this

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    }
```

Looking for a way to achieve the same with Identity. My test project is set up with MVC5, and code first

Comment: Do you use code first?

Comment: Yes. Most of the tutorials I've found online teaches MVC using code first, so I figured that must be the best practice.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended solution is to add the properties you need to the ApplicationUser class

You can also use your own "User table", in your case that would be the User class. You'd have to inherit from IdentityUser.

[**This article has examples of how to do both.**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)

Comment: Clicking on Link ,then you will get Forbidden Message.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rui.

Here is a site that will teach you [How to Extend Identity Accounts and also Implement Based Authentication.](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx)  When I was starting with Identity, that site taught me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As a related hint: Watch out when you implement a Unit of Work pattern in your project. ASP.NET identities datacontext needs to be the same as the Uow datacontext, otherwise the whole think will crash.

A good starting point may be this: [ASP.NET Identity with Repository and Unit of Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226140/asp-net-identity-with-repository-and-unit-of-work)